# MVC model getting error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting error when trying to load tab.

Error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'Mvc5.Models.IndexModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of
>   type 'Mvc5.Models.ORDERMetadata'.

order controller

```
  public ActionResult order()
    {
       IndexModel models = new IndexModel();

        return View(models);
    }
```

IndexModel.cs

```
        public class IndexModel
        {
            public ORDERMetadata GeneralTab { get; set; }
            public ORDER_DETAILSMetadata ItemTab { get; set; }
            //public ThirdTabModel ThirdTab { get; set; }

        }
```

order.cshtml

```
@model Mvc5.Models.IndexModel

<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Total</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div id="tabs-1">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_Partial_General_Tab", Model.GeneralTab);}  <===== ERRROR HERE!
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_Partial_Item_Tab", Model.ItemTab);}
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
        Content for Tab 3 goes here.<br />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
        sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </div>

</div>
```

_partial_General_Tab.cshtml

```
@model Mvc5.Models.ORDERMetadata

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Order",
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "target"
            }))
    {

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        Enter model data here....   

        <button id="editorder" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>



    }
```

_Partial_Item_Tab.cshtml

```
@model Mvc5.Models.ORDER_DETAILSMetadata


    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Items", "Order",
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "target"
            }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        Enter model data here....   

        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" />

    }
```

Comment: show `_Partial_General_Tab` and `_Partial_Item_Tab` partials also.

Comment: @Kartikeya, he might have identified the issue after seeing your comment :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be occurring because the `GeneralTab` and/or `ItemTab` properties of `IndexModel` are `null` (in which case the `ViewDataDictionary` passed to the partials will be`IndexModel`. Ensure you initialize the properties before your pass the model the view.

```
public ActionResult order()
{
  IndexModel models = new IndexModel();
  models.GeneralTab = new ORDERMetadata();
  models.ItemTab = new ORDER_DETAILSMetadata();
  return View(models);
}
```

Alternatively initialize them in a parameter-less constructor for `IndexModel`